# Use Remote Desktop with custom DPI

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, dpi

How can I change (increase) the DPI of a remote desktop session?

I am using two Windows 7 PC - both are already set to 125% on Control Panel/Display/Make it easier to read.

Yet when I open a Remote Desktop from one machine to the other the remote desktop is displayed at 100% (tiny).

How can I have the Remote Desktop displayed at 125%?

Comment: The only way to make remote picture bigger I found is to set lower resolution for the local PC's (client's) monitor (which looks ugly to be honest). My case: Win 7 (client) connects to the remote headless Win 10.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I eventually found a solution to this via this blog post by [Falafel Software](https://web.archive.org/web/20160405041739/http://blog.falafel.com/remote-desktop-on-a-high-dpi-screen/).

Basically:

- Download Microsoft's souped-up RDP client called **Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.2** (edit: no longer available so try your luck with [Remote Desktop Connection Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rdcman) - see notes below)
- When you add a new server, go to the 'Remote Desktop Settings' tab of the Properties and select 'Same as client area'
- Remote Desktop Connection Manager will then display the remote machine using the client machines DPI settings.

I've written this up in a bit more detail with screenshots [on my blog](http://www.codeulike.com/2014/05/remote-desktop-on-high-dpi-screens.html).

edit: Sounds like this might only work with Windows 8 clients, getting reports doesn't work the same way with Windows 7 clients.

edit: Microsoft is no longer offering V2.2, only V2.7. Sounds like it will still work if you tweak the settings:  Browse to the location of RDCMan.exe. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Remote Desktop Connection Manager by default). Right click RDCMan.exe select properties, select the Compatibility tab and uncheck "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings"

Comment: Does not appear to work when using Windows 7 as the client, at least in my experience. The referenced blog post has more info. It sounds like Win8 vs Win7 might be an important variable.

Comment: Using Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.7, along with the settings fix worked for me.  (Win 10 RDP into Win 7).  Note: I had installed the hotfix mentioned by Yngvar Johnsen first (on the Win 7 machine), so not sure if that helped or not.

Comment: Win 10 RDP into Win 7 (without the hotfix) works as promised. If i understand the hotfix alternative correctly, _this_ is a better solution as there is no manual manipulation of the DPI setting and RDCMan is a better way to RDP anyway

Comment: "select Compatibility tab and uncheck "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" - this worked for me without installing the fix on remote

Comment: This actually works for me using Win 7 client - Win 7 remote.  Installed hotfix on remote, set scaling on remote to 125% and the normal Win 7 rdp client now displays the scaled session properly. Thanks!

Comment: uncheck "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" -- this did not work for me with with the remote being Windows 2016 Server Azure VM, and the local machine Windows 7

Comment: Any idea where I can get this now that MS has removed V2.7 from their site?

Answer (score 37):

Microsoft has released a hotfix enabling the DPI setting for RDP sessions. 
Hotfix info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2726399. 
Hotfix downloads:

32-bit: http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%207/Windows%20Server2008%20R2%20SP1/sp2/Fix396134/7600/free/451040_intl_i386_zip.exe

64-bit: https://hotfixv4.trafficmanager.net/Windows%207/Windows%20Server2008%20R2%20SP1/sp2/Fix396134/7600/free/451041_intl_x64_zip.exe

Also note that you have to manually either choose to open this file as administrator, or choose a different unzip location. Then run the smaller file that comes out, which will automatically elevate as it should.

Comment: Presumably you install this on the destination machine rather than the one you are remoting from?

Comment: To answer myself: Yes, install the hotfix on the remote machine.

Comment: In case you are leary of hotfixes, this one is dated July 19, 2012. One would hope it is stable or MS would have pulled or updated it.

Comment: "This hotfix is no longer available"

Comment: I found another mirror: http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?showtopic=17457&hl=2726399

Comment: Another 64-bit mirror: https://mpowersoftware.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200824664-Display-settings-can-t-be-changed-from-a-Remote-Session

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I have found and elegant and easy solution to this issue.

[Change Text Size](http://www.michelstevelmans.com/change-text-size-remote-desktop-session/) is a small application written by Michel Stevelmans which will allow a user to change their DPI settings.  I have tested it on Windows 7 and it has worked wonderfully.

Here is a link to the KBB article in regards to this issue: [KB2544872](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2544872)

Comment: Themed font sizes are not the same as the DPI setting. DPI affects more than window metrics and system default font sizes.

Comment: Michel Stevelmans works like a charm.

Comment: Michel Stevelmans' link is dead (2020 December).

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been provided by Remote Desktop Connection Manager @ Sysinternals (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rdcman), currently in version v2.83.

I can connect from a Windows 11 with the scale at 175% (27 inch monitor) to a remote Windows 10 and it is perfectly visible as long as I enable the "Same as client area" option.

Thanks to all.