# Windows 7 remote desktop and screen font size

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use Remote Desktop with custom DPI](https://superuser.com/questions/294002/use-remote-desktop-with-custom-dpi)

I have my Windows 7 x64 PC set to use screen fonts at 125% (Medium).

However, when I remote desktop to that PC from Vista x32 screen fonts are regular size again (smaller).

When I go to "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display" on remote PC it shows "The display settings can't be changed from a remote session" and, interestingly enough, "Medium - 125%" is selected but all radio buttons are disabled.

Is there a way to have larger screen fonts under remote desktop?