# Remote desktop DPI (RD from Mac to Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Essentially this is my question:
[Use Remote Desktop with custom DPI](https://superuser.com/questions/294002/use-remote-desktop-with-custom-dpi)

But here is caveat:
I'm remoting from Mac to Windows 10

I didn't find any mentioning how to do it with Win 10 and solution proposed in above link is for old RD client for Windows.

I can use either Royal TSX or Microsoft Remote desktop. Both result in RD session with 100% DPI. On a remote machine I can't change DPI. But it's set to 150% when I work normally..

This basically make my goal of working remotely not achievable :( I can't see a screen..

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, neither the stable release of Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac nor their current beta release support DPI scaling. I just checked again and wasn't able to find any settings related to this.

Royal TSX on the other hand supports using the full retina resolution of your Mac and automatically adjusting the remote DPI scaling when the connection is established. In a recent beta release support for adjusting the remote DPI scaling even without using a retina screen was added.
The beta is available [here](https://www.royalapplications.com/go/kb-ts-mac-downloadbeta).

*Disclaimer: I'm the developer of Royal TSX (for macOS).*

Comment: I have confirmed that Royal TSX does indeed support native DPI scaling! So you can RDP on a 1920x1080 monitor with 150% DPI scaling with sharp text. Unlike Microsoft's Remote Desktop for Mac (even v10), it only does the fuzzy scaling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/), a free implementation of the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP). It [supports display scaling](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/pull/2756) in a client.

On macOS, you can install via Brew: `brew install freerdp`.