# How to increase text size (DPI) on Azure VM Windows Server 2016 remote desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, azure, windows-server

How do I increase the DPI (i.e. text size) on an Azure VM remote desktop?

On my machine (Windows 7), I can go to `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display` and change the zoom to `Medium` or `Large`.

On the Azure VM (Windows Server 2016), the same setting takes me to display, "which can't be changed by a remote session". Azure VM can only be used via a remote session. So how do I change it?

---

**Update**: "Set a custom scaling level (Not recommended)" in the Control panel does not seem to work -- even after logging out and in text is the same size.

**Update**: I also tried using Remote Desktop Manager 2.7 and unchecking the "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" here: [Use Remote Desktop with custom DPI](https://superuser.com/questions/294002/use-remote-desktop-with-custom-dpi/760284), but that did not work either.