# Win7 Remote Desktop to Win7 Not Scaling Correctly

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I decided to trash my Win10 Creator Update development PC and return to Win7 for a more "comfortable" environment.  I also had some issues with the Creator Update, which are not relevant now.

I am attempting to establish a remote desktop connection from my Win7 laptop to my Win7 dev box.  While the connection will establish, the display will not scale correctly or consistently.

By that I mean, If I boot the PC, then login via RDP, the display is not scaled.  If I log into the PC, the display is scaled (I had changed it to 125% via the Display control panel).  If remain logged in, then establish an RDP session, I get a properly scaled remote session!

I have tried adjusting the login screen DPI settings to 125%, with no change in behaviour.  I did a search through the registry and changed all of the LogPixels settings from 0x60 to 0x78.  Even rebooted.  No dice - I only get a scaled RDP session if I first log into the remote PC prior to establishing an RDP session.

Clearly, this will be annoying, so, looking for ways to fix. I never had this problem with Server 2012R2.

Comment: IIRC, scaling was optimized with Windows 8 (which is the basis for Windows Server 2012, thus you don't have that many issues with it)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://superuser.com/a/760284/298934) post held the answer for me. Hotfix installed on the remote did the trick.