# The display settings can't be changed from a remote session

Tags: remote-desktop

I have following setup:

- A Windows 7 client
- A Windows 10 Pro server that has RDP enabled

The client is connecting via RDP to the server.

For years, it was possible that that the Windows 10 Pro had a large DPI scaling (250%).

But suddenly, 1 week ago, the DPI scaling has been reset to 100%, and cannot be changed anymore (error message "The display settings can't be changed from a remote session"). I Googled for hours and tried every fix I could find, e.g. the Registry setting "IgnoreClientDesktopScaleFactor". Nothing helps.

The weird thing is that no updates on the Win7 or Win10 machine was applied. I don't see any cause why the DPI scaling has been disabled.

I have read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/294002/use-remote-desktop-with-custom-dpi) that "Remote Desktop Connection Manager" would solve the problem, however, this tool cannot be downloaded from Microsoft anymore, because there is a security vulnerability...

I also tried a Windows 10 => Windows 10 RDP connection, both with normal RDP application, and RDP "app" from Microsoft Store. Both don't support DPI scaling either.

Comment: if you go to the start menu and type "make text" and click "make text size bigger" you should get a settings window with two settings for text size in it: "Make text bigger" and "make everything bigger". Are you unable to change either of these settings?

Comment: I can do "Make text bigger", but it breaks applications, since the controls stay the same size, only the font gets increased. (And Delphi applications don't scale at all).  The setting "Make everything bigger", which is the one I desire, shows "The display settings can't be changed from a remote session".

Comment: maybe a workaround?: with the default windows remote desktop client you should be able to set the resolution in the display tab. Then you can save the connection file and edit it to enable [smart sizing](https://blog.concurrency.com/blog/w/smart-sizing-exposed-in-remote-desktop-ui,-at-last) which would allow you to make the window bigger. So for example you could set the remote resolution to 1024x768 and then resize the client window to larger than 1024x768 effectively increasing the size of everything (although it might look crappy)

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I have enabled "Smart sizing" , but it only allows a down-scale, but no stretching, so I can make the 800x600 window smaller, but I cannot make it bigger

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at 2 things:

1. [Remote Desktop's Display tab to toggle screen size](https://ticket.summithosting.com/hc/en-us/articles/4570661636119-How-To-Adjust-Display-Settings-Within-RDP-Windows)

[image: Remote Desktop Toggle Screen Size]

2. Look to see if the desktop's display resolution (NOT remote desktop) on the monitor is very big, but the text/app size setting is also high (above 100%).

[image: high resolution with large text size]